# TinyDB search an object imbedded in a list

Tags: python, tinydb

How do I search an object imbedded in a list? The user needs to be able to search for a title's text.

Here's the JSON:

```
"titles": [
    {
      "languageCode": "da", 
      "text": "Odysseus"
    }
  ],
```

Here's the code:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('db.json')
Event = Query()
db.search(Event.titles.text == 'Odysseus')
```

But the above example is obviously not right.

Answer (score 2):

Create a second Query object and use that to search your list object:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('db.json')
Event = Query()
Title = Query()
db.search(Event.titles.any(Title.text == 'Odysseus'))
```

This is not immediately obvious from the TinyDB [docs](http://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#advanced-queries).